# Jquery autocomplete get value

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete

auto complete is working fine. I put a hidden value for saving the value of auto complete by this method 
my code :

```
$("#cityOp").autocomplete({
        source : function(request, response) {      

        var city_value = jQuery("#cityOp").val();


        $.ajax({
            url: "city.html",

            dataType: "json", 
            data : {
                filter : city_value
            },           


            success : function(data) {

                response(jQuery.map(data.cities,function(item) {
                                    return {
                                        value : item.locationName,
                                        key : item.locationId

                                    };
                                }));
                },
select : function(event, ui) {

         $("#theHidden").val(ui.item.key) ;
    }

    });
```

then I want to get this location Id for saving the value of location , so I 
tried the as:

```
save(){
var locationValue=$("#theHidden").val(); 
//other saving codes
}
```

but I got  here locationValue is undefined .

How I get the this hidden value in save function ?
autocomplete function is in document on ready and save function is in a js.

Comment: is select function firing? put alert(ui.item.locationId); in select function. i would not put selected value in separate control but in calling autocomplete: $(this).data("value", ui.item.locationId);

Comment: Is your `save()` function defined properly? With the `function` keyword? Is the value coming in and **being set** properly? Is it being set undefined in the first place, you can check in your browsers debugger.

Comment: @elrado I had amistake in select function I changed  $("#theHidden").val(ui.item.locationId) ; into $("#theHidden").val(ui.item.key) ; put alert as alert(ui.item.key); then alert showing the hidden value

Comment: but didn't get in save function

Comment: any solution  ? pls help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this solved

```
select : function(event, ui) {

        setLocationValue(ui.item.key);
    }
```

in js

```
var locationValue;

function setLocationValue(value){
    locationValue=value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the response of the $ajax method you are mapping the data to a JSON object with only two properties, value and key.

Then, in the select, you are using a property that doesn't exist anymore.

If you want those original values to still exist, you should map them as well. Alternatively, you could save the id to the hidden field like this:

```
$("#theHidden").val(ui.item.key);
```

Let me know if that doesn't work for you.

Comment: my question is, in save function how to get the hidden value ? I put like var locationValue=$("#theHidden").val(ui.item.key); then got "ui is not defined".